# Why select location in Azure Static Web Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

According to the [Azure Static Web Apps Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/overview#key-features), one of the key features of the Azure Static Web Apps service is:

> Globally distributed static content, putting content closer to your users.

If it is globally distributed, what is the purpose of selecting the location for new resources which is nearest to us during the setting up phase as stated in step 8 of this [creating a static web app guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/getting-started?tabs=react#create-a-static-web-app)?

[image]

Does selecting "Central US" limit the static content to be only distributed in "Central US" and website visitors from other regions will all be routed back to "Central US"?

Answer (score 2):

Here the location is for Azure static web apps which is a part of the AppService , but the "Globally distributed static content, putting content closer to your users" is relevant to CDN.

For website owners who have visitors in multiple geographic locations, content will be delivered faster to these users as there is less distance to travel. CDN users also benefit from the ability to easily scale up and down much more easily due to traffic spikes

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sajeetharan. I selected East Asia as the resource location for my project, but when I use TRACERT command-line utility to trace the route taken from Malaysia to my website, it is stated that the packet is routed to Hong Kong. According to [Azure Content Delivery Network documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-pop-locations), there is a POP in Malaysia, why does it still route me to Hong Kong?

Comment: Probably Hong Kong has the lowest latency in this case, you can do a latency test from your location and see

Comment: How do I get the IP addresses of the POP in Malaysia?

Comment: Thats a separate question, if you are in malaysia just check which one has the lowest latency from here https://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/RegionToRegionLatency

Comment: Thanks for the link, according to it, the latency between South East Asia to South East Asia is "NaN". If I'm from Malaysia, isn't the nearest POP station will produce the lowest latency?

Comment: No, its not like that. Some of the regions have better connectivity even though they are not close by .

Comment: So how do I check? As the link above is stating "NaN" for latency between South East Asia to South East Asia.

Answer (score 2):

The `location` argument refers to the location where your (serverless) backend APIs will be hosted via Azure Function Apps

Comment: Is it possible to add a reference for this information?

Comment: Have a look at this pulled straight from the Azure REST API not terribly well documented https://azure.stackql.io/providers/azure/web_apps/static_sites/